# Yeoman generator-angular : 'task wiredep' is not in gulpfile & $.useref.restore is not a function

Tags: gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular, gulp-useref

I've just started using Yeoman to scaffold a new Angular app. I followed the installation guide at [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) but chose to use gulp instead of grunt for the task runner.

After installation I received error : `task 'wiredep' is not in you gulpfile`.

I tried running the build using `gulp` and received error : `TypeError: $.useref.restore is not a function`

If I run `gulp serve`, the resulting page does not wire dependencies.

Is there a fix to the errors above?

I noticed that Yeoman uses grunt, and that gulp is experimental, so I guess the above errors are expected. Should I post it as an issue at the generator's GitHub page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few issues in there.

1st issue yeoman is referring to gulp wiredep not gulp bower:
rename `gulp.task('bower', function ()`to `{ gulp.task('wiredep', function () {`

2nd issue is that bower libs are not in the `directory: yeoman.app + '/bower_components'`, but in `directory: 'bower_components'`,

3rd issue `.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app + '/views'));`is not in the views folder but the `.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app ));`

So long story short, replace `gulp.task('bower', function ...`with:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
.pipe(wiredep({
  directory: 'bower_components',
  ignorePath: '..'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app ));
});
```

Delete the dist folder, run `gulp wiredep`, `gulp` and `gulp serve` or add wiredep task to the build one.

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: It's working for 'build' task but when I run gulp 'serve' task doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Console log output would be nice... But try to change the port. Server started without a problem for me (out of the box), just that the index was missing wired dependencies.

Comment: @PatrikBego After changes you recommended, the error is gone but Bower  components are still not linked. The error are simple 404s for all of bower components:GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 
(index):75 GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js 
(index):76 GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js 
(index):77 GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 
(index):78 GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js ... and it continues!

Comment: @user1242321 see this issue: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1299. In there you'll find a Gulpfile that works.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problem.
I solved it by do the changes below to the gulp task 'client:build'.
HOWEVER, solving this will just get you to the next problem.
Watch doesn't work, live reload doesn't work and then I had no more time trying to find more issues.
But I see your bug reported on Github (Linking for reference: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1199) so lets hope someone can fix it.

Also, as you said, Gulp is experimental in this generator.

```
gulp.task('client:build', ['html', 'styles'], function() {
var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

var assets = $.useref.assets({
    searchPath: [yeoman.app, '.tmp']
});

return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.minifyCss({
      cache: true
    }))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});
```