# gulp build fails on yo angular

Tags: angularjs, gulp, wiredep

I have tried many times to init a webapp by "yo angular" and chosen gulp instead of grunt,but failed with

```
Task 'wiredep' is not in your gulpfile  
 Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

then without any moving on task.
when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop it and run with "gulp serve" or "gulp", it shows no error or warning, but the browser's console shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined".
then I tried to replace

```
gulp.task('bower', function () {  
    return gulp.src(paths.views.main)  
    .pipe(wiredep({  
        directory: yeoman.app + '/bower_components',  
        ignorePath: '..'  
    })) " 
.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app + '/views'));
});
```

with

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {  
    return gulp.src(paths.views.main)  
    .pipe(wiredep({  
       directory:  'bower_components',  
       ignorePath: '..'  
     }))", 
.pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.app ));
});
```

and delete the dist folder, just do like this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459298/yeoman-generator-angular-task-wiredep-is-not-in-gulpfile-useref-restore/36073950#36073950)
and I have also tried to update my npm, but they all don't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using gulp-angular-generator

Comment: take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459298/yeoman-generator-angular-task-wiredep-is-not-in-gulpfile-useref-restore/36073950#36073950

Comment: @rick Thanks, I have already tried to do like this, but it doesn't work

Comment: @tommoc Yes. I start the task with "yo"-->"angular"-->"gulp instead of grunt"……sorry that I can't understand what your point is.

Comment: You can use yeoman generator , https://github.com/swiip/generator-gulp-angular#readme

Comment: @tommoc he is already using it

Comment: @tommoc Thanks, fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I still can't figure out why should this problem truns out, I learn to use yeoman for just a few days. For me, I start with "yo-->angular-->gulp", when I choose grunt but not gulp, there wasn't any problem. But by running "npm install -g generator-gulp-angular", I can really finish a webapp with gulp and angular correctly!